# Install elastix in centos 6.7 on cloud server

Tags: linux, centos6, elastix

I want to install elastix 2.5 on my sever.

```
yum install -y elastix
```

then I got this error

```
Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 2009020507:asterisk-1.8.20.0-0.x86_64 (iso)
           Requires: libcurl.so.3()(64bit)
           Available: curl-7.15.5-15.el5.x86_64 (iso)
               libcurl.so.3()(64bit)
           Installed: curl-7.19.7-46.el6.x86_64 (@base)
               Not found
Error: Package: 2009020507:asterisk-1.8.20.0-0.x86_64 (iso)
           Requires: librpmio-4.4.so()(64bit)
           Available: rpm-libs-4.4.2.3-31.el5.x86_64 (iso)
               librpmio-4.4.so()(64bit)
           Installed: rpm-libs-4.8.0-47.el6.x86_64 (@base)
               Not found
Error: Package: 1:perl-Archive-Tar-1.39.1-1.el5_5.2.noarch (iso)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
           Available: 4:perl-5.8.8-38.el5_8.x86_64 (iso)
               perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
           Installed: 4:perl-5.10.1-141.el6_7.1.x86_64 (@updates)
               Not found
           Available: 4:perl-5.10.1-141.el6.x86_64 (base)
               Not found
Error: Package: 2009020507:asterisk-1.8.20.0-0.x86_64 (iso)
           Requires: librpm-4.4.so()(64bit)
           Available: rpm-libs-4.4.2.3-31.el5.x86_64 (iso)
               librpm-4.4.so()(64bit)
           Installed: rpm-libs-4.8.0-47.el6.x86_64 (@base)
               Not found
Error: Package: elastix-portknock-0.0.1-0.x86_64 (iso)
           Requires: libpcap.so.0.9.4()(64bit)
           Available: 14:libpcap-0.9.4-15.el5.x86_64 (iso)
               libpcap.so.0.9.4()(64bit)
           Available: 14:libpcap-1.4.0-4.20130826git2dbcaa1.el6.i686 (base)
               Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Seem the error say need to downgrade each package. But it is so very conflict, especially on the curl. 
Is there any possible solution to get through with the error or any alternative ways? I just want to install elastix on centos 6.7.
Is there anyone who can help? 
Thanks in advance.